# How to use GraphQL Playground or Appolo Sandbox with Nest.js microservice?

Tags: graphql, microservices, nestjs, graphql-playground

I have a microservice:

```
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { MicroserviceOptions, Transport } from '@nestjs/microservices';

import { AppModule } from './app.module';

async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.createMicroservice<MicroserviceOptions>(
    AppModule,
    {
      transport: Transport.KAFKA,
      options: {
        client: {
          brokers: ['localhost:9092'],
        },
        consumer: {
          groupId: 'auth-consumer',
        },
      },
    },
  );
  app.listen();
}
bootstrap();
```

I would like to use GQL Playground but the documentation only refers to default factory (`NestFactory.create()` instead of `NestFactory.createMicroservice()`). They do `app.listen(XXXX)` and just have to navigate to `localhost:XXXX/graphql`.

My microservice works with Kafka and is not part of my API gateway, how can I test my GQL endpoints on the GQL Playground ?

Comment: How are you using GQL with Kafka? I'm not sure I understand what's happening here

Answer (score 0):

maybe this will help you!

```
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { MicroserviceOptions, Transport } from '@nestjs/microservices';

import { AppModule } from './app.module';

async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);

  app.connectMicroservice<MicroserviceOptions>({
    transport: Transport.KAFKA,
    options: {
      client: {
        clientId: 'classroom',
        brokers: [process.env.KAFKA_BROKERS as string],
      },
      consumer: {
        groupId: 'purchases',
      },
    },
  });

  app.startAllMicroservices().then(() => {
    console.log('[MICROSERVICE] is running!');
  });

  app.listen(process.env.APP_PORT || 3000).then(() => {
    console.log('[HTTP/GRAPHQL] is running!');
  });
}
bootstrap();
```